# Поиск и замена строки html на js

Tags: javascript, json

Есть HTML страница, в которой есть:

```
<script>
"download":"https://example.ru/tvseries/705f0bb/a28d21ac3:2708/360.mp4"}]}], hlsconfig: {
            p2pConfig: {
                logLevel: true,
                live: false, // set to true in live mode
            }
        }, preroll:"https://example.ru/tvseries/705f0bb/a28d21ac3:2708/360.mp4 or https://example.ru/tvseries/705f0bb/a28d21ac3:2708/360.mp4", cuid:"-4847", "poster":"/player/preview.jpg"});
 </script>.
```

Нужно с помощью JS найти вот эту строчку:

```
preroll:"https://example.ru/tvseries/705f0bb/a28d21ac3:2708/360.mp4 or https://example.ru/tvseries/705f0bb/a28d21ac3:2708/360.mp4"
```

И заменить содержимое на

```
preroll:"https://example.ru/360.mp4"
```

Суть всей проблемы в том, что нельзя использовать jquery. Только чистый JS.
Так же, сам скрипт почти всегда разный, но `preroll: "123"` всегда присутствует.

Comment: У вас невалидный js в теге `script`

Comment: @stepan-kasyanenko, да, это просто пример. Это всё находится в переменной, но как с помощью другого скрипта можно это найти?

Comment: Я не вижу у вас в примере переменной, я вижу непонятный кусок невалидного кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если, как вы написали, данные хранятся в переменной, то достаточно [Регулярных выражений](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) для поиска и замены.

```html
<script>

var html = `
"download":"https://example.ru/tvseries/705f0bb/a28d21ac3:2708/360.mp4"}]}], hlsconfig: {
            p2pConfig: {
                logLevel: true,
                live: false, // set to true in live mode
            }
        }, preroll:"https://example.ru/tvseries/705f0bb/a28d21ac3:2708/360.mp4 or https://example.ru/tvseries/705f0bb/a28d21ac3:2708/360.mp4", cuid:"-4847", "poster":"/player/preview.jpg"});
 `;

html = html.replace(
    /preroll:".*?(\d+.mp4)"/gm,
    'preroll:"https://example.ru/$1"'
);

console.log(html);

</script>
```

Comment: Крутой ответ, но тут же возникает другой вопрос, а если мне не известно, как называется переменная, но можно точно сказать, что внутри неё есть preroll?

Comment: В таком случае есть огромный шанс, что средствами js на странице получить доступ к данной переменной не получиться(пример: [jsfiddle.net/u9woa8s5](https://jsfiddle.net/u9woa8s5)). С другой стороны, стоит ли идти таким путём?